# Is there a way to teleport player after countdown timer hits zero? on unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm very new to scripting and to unity as well, In my scene, I would like the player from its current location to teleport to a certain location after the countdown timer hits zero, is there a way to do this? I research online however I could not find many tips about it  thus I am asking here.

I did a basic code timer I found online

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float timeRemaining = 150;
    public bool timerIsRunning = false;
    public Text timeText;

    private void Start()
    {
        // Starts the timer automatically
        timerIsRunning = true;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (timerIsRunning)
        {
            if (timeRemaining > 0)
            {
                timeRemaining -= Time.deltaTime;
                DisplayTime(timeRemaining);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Time has run out!");
                timeRemaining = 0;
                timerIsRunning = false;
            }
        }
    }

    void DisplayTime(float timeToDisplay)
    {
        timeToDisplay += 1;

        float minutes = Mathf.FloorToInt(timeToDisplay / 60);
        float seconds = Mathf.FloorToInt(timeToDisplay % 60);

        timeText.text = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", minutes, seconds);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many ways to do the "teleport", but it's basically change object transform position, so if you want that the object goes to the 3D space position `(0,1,0)`, just assign it to it:

```
this.transform.position = new Vector3(0,1,0);
```

For the timer you can use [Invoke](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html) or [InvokeRepeating](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html) methods or a countdown like yours.

So in your code it will looke something like:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
///
    public GameObject objectToTeleport = null; //assign it from inspector or code
    public Vector3 destination = new Vector3(0,0,0); //assign it from inspector or code
///
    public float timeRemaining = 150;
    public bool timerIsRunning = false;
    public Text timeText;

    private void Start()
    {
        // Starts the timer automatically
        timerIsRunning = true;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (timerIsRunning)
        {
            if (timeRemaining > 0)
            {
                timeRemaining -= Time.deltaTime;
                DisplayTime(timeRemaining);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Time has run out!");
                timeRemaining = 0;
                timerIsRunning = false;
                //Move object
                objectToTeleport.transform.position = destination;
            }
        }
    }

    void DisplayTime(float timeToDisplay)
    {
        timeToDisplay += 1;

        float minutes = Mathf.FloorToInt(timeToDisplay / 60);
        float seconds = Mathf.FloorToInt(timeToDisplay % 60);

        timeText.text = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", minutes, seconds);
    }
}
```